# C/C++/Java interpreter

Tags: java, c++, c, interpreter

Why has no one ever made a C/C++/Java interpreter which requires no compilation to run? It can't be that hard to make something akin to IDLE for Python.

The same goes for other languages such as FORTRAN, Pascal and others. Is there some kind of code based reason for this or is it just that people prefer to compile their code.

Comment: What is `C/C++/Java`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Either C, C++ or Java. I couldn't be bother to write it out in full.

Comment: I've come across a C++ interpreter before. It was terrible,

Comment: [CINT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Is it good?

Comment: I've used a bit of trial.

Comment: @user12321 CINT is the one I was referring to. It was abysmal. It might have improved, but I'd be surprised.

Comment: I don't remember the name of it, but we shipped several games that used a C interpreter for scripting 10+ years ago.

Comment: There is a C interpreter here: https://www.softintegration.com/download/ . If you just want to put C code in a text file and run it, this will give you that ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C and C++ are languages designed to be compiled and generate fast and efficient code.

Interpreters, by the definition that they "interpret" the code, are generally slow (or at least slower than the same compiled language, assuming a good compiler).

However, there are combinations of clang and llvm-jit that could be (and has been) built into an "interpreted version of C or C++". I think there are some limitations, and I've never actually used it.

There is no great technical reason NOT to do this, it's just that it's about the same amount of work, if not more than, the work to write a compiler, and the end result of writing a compiler is "better".

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts.

All interpreters have to have a lexer/parser stage (although there has been some academic work on incremental compilers).

There is no point in having an interpreter for Java when an IDE can constantly maintain the "all compiled" status.

I've known some interpreters in parallel to compilers, and one sad thing happening there was that the actual languages processed by the "cousins" were not really compatible, which made development on the interpreter risky.

A thing like the JVM makes it less and less desirable to "roll your own".

There used to be an interpreter for a Pascal subset IIRC: P-Pascal) from Wirth's own group. A good study object for students, but a toy for serious SW development.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one sane reason to implement an interpreter for a language which is otherwise perfectly compilable: to have a formal definition of its operational semantics, which, in turn, can be used to derive static code analysis tools, code rewrite tools, various verification engines and so on.

Take a look at [this C interpreter](https://code.google.com/p/c-semantics/) for example.